# Spring @validated is not cascaded to fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I need to use groups so that I can use the same DTO for creating and patching; however, the requirements for these operations are obviously different. Therefore, I decided to use Spirng's **@Validated** instead of **@Valid** along with groups. Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
class PersonDto{ 
@NotBlank(groups = CreateConstraint.class)
private String phoneNumber;
@NotNull(groups = CreateConstraint.class)
@Valid
private AddressDto address;
}
```

and in the AddressDto, I have used the default group:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AddressDto {
@NotBlank
private String line1;
private String line2; 
private String city;
@NotNull
private Province province;
@NotBlank
private String postalCode;
}
```

And the controller:

```
@PatchMapping("/patch")
public void patchPerson(@RequestBody @Validated PersonDto dto) {
personService.patchPerson(dto);}
```

In the controller here I am using the default group as well. Now, unless I explicitly add `@Valid` to the AddressDto declaration in PersonDto, the validation is not done for the AddressDto. why is it that *@Validated is not cascaded to the fields inside the PersonDto*? Thanks.

**Edit**:
Just to be clear [`@Valid` does validate recursively](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine). wondering why `@Validated` not...

Comment: Because this is the behaviour JSR describe. You have to explicitely define the validation points on the object graph.

Comment: it happens for Valid though, why not Validated? ...JSR303 says: The @Valid annotation on a given association (i.e. object reference or collection, array, Iterable of objects), dictates the Bean Validator implementation to apply recursively the Bean Validation routine on (each of) the associated object(s). This mechanism is recursive: an associated object can itself contain cascaded references.

Comment: Validated was designed for validating group of informations. For example, in the first step you validate only form1 values then form2 etc inside a workflow. So you can use it like this: @Validation(ClassToValidateForm1), in your model you can add group to your fields like
@Email(group=ClassToValidateForm1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the validation group to the cascaded fields as well.
For example, check the line1 field for the CreateConstraint group.
Also, you have to specify the validation group in the controller.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AddressDto {
    @NotBlank(groups = CreateConstraint.class)
    private String line1;
    private String line2; 
    private String city;
    @NotNull()
    private Province province;
    @NotBlank()
    private String postalCode;
}

@PatchMapping("/patch")
public void patchPerson(@RequestBody @Validated({CreateConstraint.class})PersonDto dto) {
    personService.patchPerson(dto);
}
```

Comment: Incorrect, you can use the default group. but that was not the question. Even if you add them and use @Validated in the controller, you still need to use Valid on the Address regardless for validation to cascade.